# put the value of textbox into a variable using PHP (not post method)

Tags: php, html, input, textbox

i wanna put the text that user entered in textbox in a variable
i don't want to send it to another page.
how can i do it!
in asp.net it would be :

```
string a = textbox1.text;
```

how could i do it using php?

html :

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="news">
</body>
</html>
```

php variable :

```
$news_text;
```

i wanna put text that user entered into $news_text
please help me!

Comment: You have to send the data somewhere. You have to submit a form or at least use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET uses forms. There is no way to avoid using POST/GET/etc.

```
<?php
$news_text = isset($_REQUEST['news']) ? $_REQUEST['news'] : '';
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="news"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send it to at least that same page to get a post value.

```
             $news_text = isset($_POST['news_text']) ? $_POST['news_text'] : '';
```